# Обращение к коду в try из блока catch

Tags: javascript, angular2

Можно ли из блока catch обратиться к коду из блока try, чтобы добавить в него свойства error.status, error.message...?

Comment: Вопрос несколько непонятен, поясните поподробнее, пожалуйста. Что обозначает в данном случае словосочетание "обратиться к коду"?

Comment: Приходит код (json) сервера, если по каким-то причинам он попадает в catch, нужно из catch добавить в json описание ошибки. Просто в catch попадает описание ошибки, а мне нужно достучаться и до основного кода

Comment: А если он попадет в `catch` как раз потому что по каким-то причинам `JSON` не пришёл?

Comment: Уточняйте вопрос, ведь как вы спросили, так вам и ответили.

Comment: Да, спасибо, рассматривлся вариант, что в catch он попадает после обработки, уже после того как он пришел. Но в целом, да подход неправильный - если JSON вообще не прийдет, то и записыввать будет некуда.

Answer (score 0):

Что значит "обратиться к коду"?

```
try {
    var a = {};
    throw "error";
    var b = {};
} catch (e) {
    a.error = e; //так можно
    b.error = e; //так нельзя, потому что скрипт упал раньше, чем "b" заинитилась
}
```

Comment: А вот если вместо `var` будет `let`, то этот фокус уже не пройдёт, стоит отметить этот момент. :)

Comment: Да так себе, мой лучше:)